# How to download torrents with long filenames?

Tags: bittorrent, transmission, filename

There is a [known problem](https://trac.transmissionbt.com/ticket/4189) with transmission: it can't download torrents with filenames longer than 255 bytes. What are the workarounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Deluge](https://deluge-torrent.org/), at the very least since version 2.0, it is possible to rename the files when you add the torrent by double-clicking on the file name.

I used this feature to circumvent this long filename problem without needing to dig up a FAT partition.

Answer (score 1):

I am here not to solve the problem, but to offer an alternative.

If you are not determined to use Transmission by any means, you might want to use [Vuze](http://www.vuze.com/). I invite you to download it and give it a try: `sudo apt-get install vuze`

Comment: Vuze is feature rich software but it gives lot of headache once you  get some java errors. check out Ktorrent or Miro

Comment: I agree with what you said.

Comment: Can you please add how exactly does it solve the problem?

Comment: Did you even read the answer?

Comment: Yeah) I mean: does it have a way to rename files or something else that makes downloading possible?

Comment: It just plain downloads them. It's a different torrent client.

Comment: Vuze also gets stopped on "File Name Too Long" error.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the common Linux file systems only support up to 255 characters filename lengths. Yet the FAT32 file system supports longer filenames, and Linux supports it just fine!

The solution then is to just download to a FAT32 formatted partition. Any external storage should work (we usually keep pen drives FAT32 for compatibility with Windows anyway). Or you can just create your own partition.

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't try to download the link, because it's not supported by your file system. 
Right click on magnet link, then 'copy link'. 
Open transmission -> file -> Open URL, then paste.
Voila!